# How can I fix my integrated vscode termnial

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So i'm trying to set up my `vscode` to run python, it works but the issue is I set it up in a way that when I type `./helloworld.py` in the integrated terminal, it opens up `pycharm` and I don't want that. I want it to open up python shell or output `"hello world"` in the integrated terminal. how can I fix this problem or how do I change my compiler in `vscode`?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run your file is to open your files in the editor window and then move your cursor to the editor window and right click. You get a pane that looks like so.

[image]

There is an option to run python file in terminal. Select this. The file will excute in the integrated terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```sh
python3 ./helloworld.py
```

This tells your os to use the `python3` program to run the file instead of using pycharms.

You can use the `python` command instead for python 2